# Which file runs Eclipse to start a JBoss server

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

How does Eclipse start a JBoss server (7.1.1 or EAP 6.1)? If I delete all of bin's directory content and starts JBoss server from Eclipse, Eclipse makes the start (witho some errors). I thought that Eclipse runs some .bat from bin directory, but I'm wrong. If anyone knows which file, script, jar runs, please tell me.

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse starts JBoss by directly running the main class, `org.jboss.modules.Main` in `jboss-modules.jar`.

Open the server configuration (doubleclick on the server in the 'servers' view).

There, click 'Open launch configuration'. In the dialog 'Edit Configuration' open the 'Main' tab. There you see the option for the main class, which is 'org.jboss.modules.Main' by default.